# Image and long text inline within Div

Tags: html, css

I need to display an image and some dynamic text inline within a Div.

The problem is when this text is too long the next line text start from the begibning of the Div rather than keeping left alignment of text same.

I want something like this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sort of code for us to look at? Or a website? What have you tried yet that doesn't work?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

I love to use the css background feature for this kind of task.
`padding-left` makes space for the image, so make sure to adjust that to your needs. Also you can control the image size with `background-size`.

```css
.icon-box{
 padding: 25px;
 padding-left: 75px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f087769399da5144ae10c892ae279490?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG);
 background-position: 25px center;
 background-color: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-box">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <p>This is the short or long text.  Longer than shorter.  Maybe.</p>
    </div>
</div>

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-item {
    align-self: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display an image and some dynamic text inline within a Div by use below code:

```css
div.main{ 
    border:solid black 1px;
    display:table;
    padding:5px; 
    width:100%;
    margin:5px 0; /* you can change/remove margin */
}

div.main .image{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    padding-right:5px;
    width:50px; /* you can change width */
}
div.image img{ 
    width:100%;
    height:50px; /* you can change height */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div.your-text{ 
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="image"><img src="your_iamge_link" /></div>
    <div class="your-text">Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here. Type your text here.</div>
</div>
```